# QTextStream is not outputting anything, what could I be doing wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QTextStream to output to stdout, but nothing happens unless I enter a character. I have tried including cstdlib, this did not work either.

Note: I tried removing all references to my stdin QTextStream and output worked fine.

```
    #include <QTextStream>

    QTextStream out(stdout);        
    out << "Please enter login username and password\n";
    QTextStream in(stdin);
    out << "username:";
    QString username = in.readLine();
    out << "password:";
    QString password = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to manually flush the buffer after each time you push something in the stream:

```
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out << "Please enter login username and password\n";
    out.flush();
    QTextStream in(stdin);
    out << "username:";
    out.flush();
    QString username = in.readLine();
    out << "password:";
    out.flush();
    QString password = in.readLine();
```

Alternatively, appending `<< endl` also works.

Comment: Also, as you said, while endl will cause the stream to be flushed, simply having \n at the end of the string will NOT.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Emanuele. I thought this might have been the case. After further troubleshooting, I noticed that if I used each separately in different scopes this fixed it. Thank you again.